# Can you call call perform/do functions from another function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function

I am new to PostgreSQL normally work with the MS-SQL stack, I would normally use the EXEC command inside a stored procedure to call other stored procedures, having trouble achieving the same thing in PostgreSQL.

I have written the below funciton to call the other function but I can't get it to work, can anyone see what I'm getting wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.run_elt_functions ()

DO $$
    BEGIN
    PERFORM public.update_d_customer ();
    PERFORM public.update_d_site ();
    PERFORM public.update_d_service ();
    PERFORM public.update_f_service ();
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

When I run the above code and get this error:
[2019-08-27 11:48:06] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at end of input

Can anyone help?

Comment: `DO` is an SQL statement that you use if you want to run PL/pgSQL in an SQL statement without the need to define a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be either in a `do` block, or in a function.

Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.run_elt_functions()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM public.update_d_customer();
    PERFORM public.update_d_site();
    PERFORM public.update_d_service();
    PERFORM public.update_f_service();
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```